# background-image not showing in IE8 Drupal 7 Zen Subtheme

Tags: css, drupal, internet-explorer-8

[Here](https://composer.klnpa.org/) is my site, been googling quite a lot without success. The image-background shows fine in all browsers except IE8 and below. I am not sure if this is a drupal, zen, IE or css issue (though the CSS seems fine). The CSS code is as follows:

```
header.header {
padding-top:5px;
background-image: url('/sites/all/themes/kln_theme/css/images/mocha.png');
background-repeat: repeat-xy;
}
```

Comment: Could you try background-repeat: repeat;? I don't have IE8 on the VM right now.

Comment: Indeed,`repeat-xy` is not a valid property and IE is quite strict about things like that.

Comment: I changed it to background-repeat: repeat; unfortunately without any different results.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem a couple of times.

What did the trick for me is open the image in photoshop (or something similar) and change the image modus from CMYK to RGB, if this is the case. Apparently IE has problems with showing CMYK images.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, the issue was with my emulation of IE8. Turns out that it actually works fine in IE8.